# Importing bootstrap in scss makes task slow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp

I am importing bootstrap in my main scss file to use the variables and breakpoints from bootstrap in my own scss files.

This works fine but every change I save it takes about 3 seconds to compile, when i compile it without the bootstrap include it takes 99ms.

**Is there a way to let gulp not compile bootstrap each time I make a change and still use all of the variables? (Bootstrap is not changing anyway)**

My main scss thar imports all my scss code looks like this

```
@import "assets/colors";
@import "assets/fonts";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "assets/buttons";
@import "elements/header/header";
@import "elements/header/header-usp";
@import "elements/header/nav";
@import "elements/main-content.scss";
```

My gulpfile.js looks like this

```
// Initialize modules
// Importing specific gulp API functions lets us write them below as series() instead of gulp.series()
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
// Importing all the Gulp-related packages we want to use
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');


// File paths
const files = { 
    scssPath: 'assets/style/sass/**/*.scss',
    jsPath: 'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
    distCssPath: 'assets/dist/css',
    distScriptsPath: 'assets/dist/scripts'
}

// Sass task: compiles the style.scss file into style.css
function scssTask(){    
    return src(files.scssPath)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
        .pipe(sass()) // compile SCSS to CSS
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemaps file in current directory
        .pipe(dest(files.distCssPath)
    ); // put final CSS in site/templates/dist folder
}

// JS task: concatenates and uglifies JS files to script.js
function jsTask(){
    return src([
        files.jsPath
        //,'!' + 'includes/js/jquery.min.js', // to exclude any specific files
        ])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(dest(files.distScriptsPath)
    );
}

// Cachebust
var cbString = new Date().getTime();
function cacheBustTask(){
    return src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/g, 'cb=' + cbString))
        .pipe(dest('.'));
}

// Watch task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
// If any change, run scss and js tasks simultaneously
function watchTask(){
    watch([files.scssPath, files.jsPath], 
        series(
            parallel(scssTask, jsTask)
        )
    );    
}

// Export the default Gulp task so it can be run
// Runs the scss and js tasks simultaneously
// then runs cacheBust, then watch task
exports.default = series(
    parallel(scssTask, jsTask), 
    watchTask
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i fixed it with the help of @ekans I only needed to import the necessary files so my new import looks like this and takes only +- 100MS

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
```

Comment: But how do you know which files are necessary without having a deep understanding of how Bootstrap works?  Is there some way to determine which files you actually need?

Comment: @Jim It can be found in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss`. Experiments show that importing the first block (//Configuration: functions ... utilities) is fast, and by the looks of it doesn't produce any real rules. As for future guarantees, there's none. But chances are high that everything before "//Layout & components" section is what you need, because it needs all of that too and that is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 1):

you can temporary remove `.pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ]))` to make fast compile

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing whole bootstrap, and recompile it each time, you can only import var file : `@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";`

Comment: I had to import functions and breakpoints aswell but you did get me on the right track, thanks!

'@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";'
'@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";'
'@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";'